# What namespace do I use when sending a message with VBA and CDO for SMTP?

Tags: vba, cdonts

I do not understand why every example I have seen has the schema from microsoft for the namespace.  What is it for?  Is it really sending something by looking at Microsoft servers?

[How do I use CDO with Exchange with vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283742/how-do-i-use-cdo-with-exchange-with-vbscript)

I would post my code but it and all examples all have the same thing:

`objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")= cdoSendUsingPort`

I don't want to put the microsoft schema in there.  I just want to send it to my Exchange or SMTP server.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces are there because they uniquely identify the properties within the object;

> Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 enlists the use of Uniform Resource
>   Identifiers (URIs) to qualify or scope field names and their semantic
>   definitions. Each field accessed through a Fields collection is
>   comprised of a namespace prefix and a local name. The namespace prefix
>   is a URI reference used to qualify or scope the semantic definition of
>   the property. For example, the subject field for a message has two
>   representations: one with non US-ASCII characters encoded using the
>   mechanism defined in RFC 1522, and another where these characters are
>   decoded into native, UNICODE characters. By using namespaces, one can
>   identify which semantic definition is intended when the "subject" for
>   the message is requested. In this case, the subject field defined
>   within the urn:schemas:mailheader: namespace is defined to be the
>   US-ASCII string value of the field, and the subject field defined
>   within the urn:schemas:httpmail: namespace is the native, UNICODE
>   version.

From the [MSDN article Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It's almost exactly the same principal as [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/), or even namespaces in a language like [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

They aren't actually connecting to Microsoft at all; indeed, try typing the URL into a browser, and you will get a 404 error.

It's just the rather inelegant syntax for setting the properties that you need to set in order to connect to *your* exchange server.

For example, to set the server your code should connect to for sending mail, you set the property `smtpserver`. Internally, to reach this [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527294%28v=exchg.10%29), the assembly will map this onto the URI `http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver`

A C# component for sending mail might ask you to set `SmtpMail.Server`. However, remember, to create SmtpMail, you would have had to look in the namespace `System.Web.Mail` - so the fully qualified path to the property is `System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Server` Here, however, the language is far more elegant - the using statement allows us to be in the context for creating the object, which reduces the amount of typing. Remember, if you really wanted to, in C#, you could do:

```
System.Web.Mail.SmtpServer mailServer = new System.Web.Mail.SmtpServer();
```

Which is more verbose.

In my opinion, the URI syntax is ungainly, however, at the time, it was a proposed solution to the problem of uniquely distinguishing things with the same name that could mean something different. Some people used it. A lot of people didn't. Remember, this code is over a decade old!

Comment: So I could just put any URI there?  just make something up?

Comment: Try it! I suspect not though, because, internally, it will be using those URI's to map onto certain properties, or add context, which the internals of the assembly will *expect* to be there. If you really hate it, farm out the strings into some constants and hide the URI's so you never have to look at them again.

Comment: It worked with the microsoft uri in there, but I don't understand why if it is not looking at microsoft on the Internet and not sending them anything.

Comment: I've bulked up the answer @johnny. From your history, I see you've had a little bit of exposure (at least, sorry for any assumptions) to C# so I've tried to add some context. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I thought, but my problem is why doesn't it work with any URI?  Why does it have to say the Microsoft one?  I put in http://myserver.../smtpserver and it fails.

Comment: @johnny It will be because, internally, it is using that string to set a property. It may be something as simple as a `switch` statement, or something more complex, like an XML Document. The reason you can't use any string is because it was designed to work only with those ones; it's Microsoft's component so you have to use their names and their standard for CDONTS!

Comment: oh.  I see.  So just like c#, you can't just make up something.  You have to follow the namespace from System.x.x.x.  edit:  the schema is the same as "System."  My objects look for that URI specfically just like C# looks for System.